# Sorting Algorithms in Multiple Arrays; Binary Search Function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I am supposed to take 1000000 numbers from an input.txt file and store them into one array of terms of size 10000 and another array of the frequency of each term of size 10000. For right now, I am just trying to sort a series of  7 numbers:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   0
>   3
>   2
>   0

And I am supposed to get the output:

> 0 3
>   2 2
>   1 1
>   3 1

But instead. I am getting

> 0 3
>   1 2
>   1 1
>   3 1

For some reason it isn't placing the two in the spot it needs to. I assume a problem in the `Insert()` function. But I can't find it. 
Also, as a side note. I tried to run the program with the 1,000,000 numbers but it just said SearchAndSort.exe has failed and needs to close.

Please help me out! I bet there's just some small syntax error somewhere. 
Here is my main.cpp file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "TermTable.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TermTable termTableObj;
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Open" << endl;
        int num;
        while (fin >> num)
        {
            termTableObj.Insert(num);
        }
        termTableObj.Sort();
        termTableObj.Display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my TermTable.cpp implementation file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "TermTable.h"
using namespace std;

int TermTable::BinarySearch(int searchValue)
{
    int first, last, middle, position;
    bool found;
    first = 0;
    last = currentAmount - 1;
    found = false;
    position = -1;
    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (termArray[middle] == searchValue)
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (termArray[middle] > searchValue)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;
    }
    return position;
}

void TermTable::Sort()
{
    int temp;
    bool swapOccurred;
    do {
        swapOccurred = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (currentAmount - 1); count++)
        {
            if (frequencyArray[count] < frequencyArray[count + 1])
            {
                temp = frequencyArray[count];
                frequencyArray[count] = frequencyArray[count + 1];
                frequencyArray[count + 1] = temp;
                temp = termArray[count];
                termArray[count] = frequencyArray[count + 1];
                termArray[count + 1] = temp;
                swapOccurred = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapOccurred);
}

void TermTable::Insert(int value)
{
    int position = BinarySearch(value);
    if (position != -1)
    {
        frequencyArray[position] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp;
        termArray[currentAmount] = value;
        frequencyArray[currentAmount] = 1;
        currentAmount++;
        for (int i = currentAmount + 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (termArray[i] < termArray[i - 1])
            {
                temp = termArray[i];
                termArray[i] = termArray[i - 1];
                termArray[i - 1] = temp;
                temp = frequencyArray[i];
                frequencyArray[i] = frequencyArray[i - 1];
                frequencyArray[i - 1] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void TermTable::Display()
{
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        fout << termArray[j] << " " << frequencyArray[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

And here is my class definition:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// class specification
class TermTable
{
public:
    // constructor
    TermTable()
    {
        currentAmount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            termArray[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            frequencyArray[i] = 0;
        }
    };

    // member functions
    int BinarySearch(int searchValue);
    void Insert(int value);
    void Sort();
    void Display();
    // destructor
    ~TermTable()
    {
        return;
    }
private:
    // data
    int currentAmount;
    int termArray[10000];
    int frequencyArray[10000];
};
```

Comment: That really does not look like "sorting". How can one end up with 8 items after 'sorting' 7, where two out of 3 zeroes magically disappeared? Can you sort the money in my wallet this way?

Comment: It is sorting because if a number is repeated, it is updated in the frequency array to have appeared more than once, and is not inserted again into the termArray.

Comment: @Jongware yes, you can. Unsorted you have 7 money: one dollar bill, two dollars bill, five dollars bill, one dollar bill, ten dollars bill, five dollars bill, one dollar bill. When these are sorted you have 8 values:"three" "one" dollar bills, "one" "two" dollars bill, "two" "five" dollars bills, "one" "ten" dollars bill.

Comment: I got it, the output is pairs of "item - frequency". So I *can* sort the number of $100 bills in my wallet after all.

Comment: `for (int i = currentAmount + 1; i >= 0; i--)` is not safe. It starts with i out of bounds (too high, it needs to be `currentAmount-1`)) and may end with `i=0`, so `[i-1]` is out of bounds as well. This could introduce uninitialised garbage into your array.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want a standard histogram of input values, and list them in order of decreasing frequency.

So let's do the usual insertion into a map (by the value as key) and sort the pairs by frequency decending, afterwards.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a46ca2f012e887e8)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>   // cin/cout
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <iterator>   // istream_iterator
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <functional> // mem_fn

using namespace std;
using Histo = map<int, size_t>;

int main() {
    Histo histo;
    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {}, [&](int i) { histo[i]++; });

    vector<pair<int, size_t>> v(begin(histo), end(histo));
    sort(begin(v), end(v), [](Histo::value_type a, Histo::value_type b) { return a.second > b.second; });

    for(auto& p : v)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
0 3
2 2
1 1
3 1
```

Comment: Haha. I got that completely wrong the first try. [Fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27994495/revisions)

Comment: Nice demonstration of clean and concise c++11 code. However it might be a little dense and arcane to the OP.